# Quick action to create lookup parent record

Tags: lightning-quickaction

Is it possible to create a Quick Action on a child record to create record for an object that is a lookup parent to the child?

I have various examples of having such QA as "Create Opportunity" on Account, but my use case demands the other way round, so e.g. "Create Account" QA on a Contact (might not be the greatest example but somewhat similar is my requirement, using custom objects).
Please can someone let me know if this is even possible, and any helpful links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [object-specific quick actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_object_specific_actions.htm&type=0) work based on a *relationship field* between the source object and target object **that exists on the target object**. This means that the out-of-the-box object-specific quick actions only work in the scenario you're not looking for

- Parent object button that creates child record and pre-populates
  lookup

If you need to do the opposite (Child object button creates parent record) then you need to use a different [action type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.actions_overview.htm&type=5).

A [screen flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/screen_flow_distribution/screen_flow_distribution_action) quick action is still declarative and gives you even more flexibility/customization than an object-specific quick action. You can query whatever records you want, prepopulate any field you want, and update both records (parent + child) as desired.

If, for some reason, a screen flow still doesn't give you enough customization - you can now call a [LWC from a quick action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232).